# How to migrate all projects from a solution easily

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working with a solution with 44 projects targeting the Dotnet core 2.1 framework.
I want to target 2.2 framework, Is there an easy way to do that without editing each csproj file?

I searched on the internet and I just found how to retarget one project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that *easily* fits here...

Comment: The easily I mean a Microsoft Style Solution.Before when I had to retarget to another full framework there was a migrating tool that resolves all references of all projects.

Comment: I don't know about such tool either, but I would definitely go for the solution proposed by bolov, as I have done the same thing in the past also.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of such a tool.

I personally would fire up Notepad++ >> Find in files >> Open solution folder >> filter by `.csproj` >> find a search pattern that matches the target version >> replace all

Alternatively ... just do it. Assuming 5 seconds per project that's under 4 minutes for the whole solution. If you are lazy let's say 15 seconds per project and that is still 11 minutes.

If you however do this a lot, write a quick script to do this.

Comment: But It is not just the target projects, what did you do about the nuget references?

Answer (score 0):

1) Open Visual Studio Code, navigate to Search

2) Find `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>` and Replace with `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>`

3. Run `dotnet restore` in sln folder then build solution

OR

3. Clean then build solution in the solution explorer

Comment: It is not just that. After I did that I can't restore because the NuGet packages references are for 2.1 version.

Comment: Are you not able to update the version of nuget packages in a likewise manner? For example, replacing `<PackageReference Include="whatever" Version="x.x.x.x" />` with whatever version is compatible with your new target framework, and then running `dotnet restore`?

Comment: I have a lot of packages references, I think that is not a usual and safe thing to do, but if there is not another way I'll do like you guys is telling me to do. Thanks!